# Multiply для img (наложение изображения с белым фоном на серый фон)

Tags: css, css3

Итак, часто существует необходимость наложения изображений, например, товарных позиций, на серый фон. При этом мы имеем белый фон, что часто не вяжется с дизайном страницы. Картинка для понимания вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существуют ли вообще способы наложения `<img>` на серый фон по аналогии с `background-blend-mode: multiply`?

Кусочек HTML с внешним видом, чтоб не было попыток просто продублировать то, что на картинке выше:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #f6f6f6;
text-align: center;
}
img {
max-width: 240px;
margin: 60px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunPY.jpg" />
```

Comment: если нет метода для img попробуй через js... Задавать `background` какому-нибудь элементу используя `src` от `img`, а там уже `blend-mode` Но лучше всего `png` использовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На текущий момент, самым простым и банальным способом решения вопроса стало перекрытие изображения прозрачным фоном:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 240px;
  margin: 60px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 240px;
  background: rgba(30, 30, 30, .04);
  left: 50%;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunPY.jpg" />
<div></div>
```

В этом случае, поигравшись со значениями, я полностью достигнул нужного результата, без потери контраста и сложных "костылей". Сфера применения может быть самой разнообразной. Если никто не придумает что-то лучше, буду рад принять как правильный ответ.

Comment: Мысль здравая и во многих случая может прокатить. Правда при реализации градиента на заднем плане или более темного фона все же будут проблемы. Впрочем, выбирая между `mix-blend-mode` и этим вариантом, я все же склоняюсь к вашему.

Answer (score 3):

Есть, это свойство `mix-blend-mode: multiply`.

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

figure img {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  display: block;
}

figure:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CCC;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/handsome-young-man-on-white-background-picture-id523478288?k=6&m=523478288&s=612x612&w=0&h=4JptiegzwJp1nA1ItdZSogOmqVqC02ZCFTCI32VrDDY=" />
</figure>
```

Comment: Поддержка конечно не радует, а так вариант неплохой.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev не обязательно использовать один вариант. Не забывайте о graceful degradation для тех браузеров, которые не поддерживают это свойство, воспользуйтесь `@supports`.

Comment: Спасибо. В общем-то, можно совместить оба варианта на все случаи жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать что-то типа такого:

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image> div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: gray; /*Задать фон для png, отличный от основного*/
}

.image-slider img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div>
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/chelovechestorona/images/b/b9/Bill_cipher_cat_by_ink_n_heart-d7mx1b5.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20141006131434&path-prefix=ru" alt="" />
  </div>
  <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/bakugan/images/2/2e/Aquos_Olifus.png/revision/latest?cb=20110223133315" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Вы немного не поняли вопрос. Суть не в создании разделения изображения, а в том, чтоб не используя `.png` накладывать изображения на серый фон и при этом превращать белые участки накладываемого изображения в серые (цвет фона).

Answer (score 0):

средствами css вы не измените отдельных частей растровой картинки(см. белый фон), в вашем случае подходит только использование `png`.

```css
.card{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:
    url(https://www.be-in.ru/media/beingallery/gallary/things/2014/03/12/DSC_6803.png.590x700_q95.png) no-repeat center/100px auto,
    linear-gradient(90deg,white 50%,gray 50%);
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}
.card:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:calc(50% - 1px);
  height:100%;
  border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
```